# How Scala List take() method can change a val type?

Tags: string, scala, methods, take

I just found a strange behavior with `take()` method in a String.

Here is my code:

```
val ji = Array("134","231","2321")
var t = ji
var i = ji(1).take(2)
i = i + 8
t(1)= i
println(ji.mkString(",")) //134,238,2321
println(t.mkString(","))  //134,238,2321
```

I expected that `ji` kept its value but it seems affected as well as `t`. I would like to create a new `ji` then change into `t` without touching `ji`. However, I don't want to make `ji` redundant.

Comment: Arrays are mutables, if you share a reference of an **Array** it is pointing to the same mutable region of memory. - Stay away of **Arrays** when learning the language, they are not real collections but a JVM primitive; also try to avoid mutability as much as you can.

Answer (score 3):

`val ji = Array("134","231","2321")` - Ok, `ji` is an array of strings.

`var t = ji` -- Don't need this. AVOID using `vars`

`var i = ji(1).take(2)` -- Don't need this either

`i = i + 8` - AVOID mutability. Also, `i` is a `String` and `8` is an integer. DON'T do this.

The two lines above should be rewritten as
`val i = ji(1).take(2) + "8"`

`t(1)= i` -- You are changing the array element here (as written, `t` and `ji` are *the same* array). DON'T do this.

Bottom line:

```
   val ji = Array("134","231","2321")
   val t = ji.updated(1, ji(1).take(2) + "8")
```

This does what you want: `ji` and `t` are two arrays, that differ in their second element.